# JPanel Not Stretching To Fill Screen

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

So I am trying to make a panel that stretches across my entire programs with, and has about 20 pixels worth of height. For some reason there is only a small box that is the panel. Can anybody tell me why it isn't stretching to the entire width? I'm fairly new to Java, so sorry if the code is a little messy/wrong.

## GridPane Class

```
public GridPane() {
  gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
  gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
  gbc.weighty = 1.0;
  horizontalGrid = new JButton();
  horizontalGrid.setText("Horizontal Grid");
  options = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
  options.setBackground(Color.black);
  options.add(horizontalGrid);
  add(options, gbc);
}
```

## Game Class

```
public class Game extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
   //DECLARATIONS
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public GridPane grid = new GridPane();
//DECLARATIONS END
//CONSTRUCTOR
public Game() {
    this.add(grid);     
}
//CONSTRUCTOR ENDS
//MAIN METHOD
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Game game = new Game();
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(game);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
//MAIN METHOD ENDS
//ACTION METHOD
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
}
```

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212989/jpanels-dont-completely-stretch-to-occupy-the-available-space

Comment: You set `weighty`, but you're missing something it seems. ... `weight?` perhaps?

Comment: OK, I'll be blunt and to the point -- where do you set `weightx`?

Comment: I did directly after weighty, but it didn't fix much.

Comment: @DennisMills: where -- I don't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it!! It turns out that we needed to replace the GridPane Constructor with this code:

```
setBackground(Color.black);

add(horizontalGrid);
```

I'm not exactly sure why, but it works.